# why can't i import my own classes in other classes i created?

Tags: java, class, import, package

so i have this two classes in two different packages, whenever i try to import one class into the other one it gives me "the import shui.utility cannot be resolved", it has always worked without any problems, but yesterday it started to not work anymore, i just can't find a way to use my utility class in other classes, i searched everywhere on the internet but i couldn't make it work

i tried to use my class but it didn't work, i just can't use my utility methods in any of my programs

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example which reproduces the problem. How do you build your program?

Comment: so i have two java projects, each one has a package with a class in it, i'll give you the names to be a little more clear, the first package and its class are called rispectively shui and utility, the second one is called exercises and its class name is product. i tried to import utility in product with "import shui.utility;" but it says that shui cannot be resolved. i can't figure out why it doesen't find the package, before yesterday everything was working fine, but after i couldn't import any of my classes in my other classes

Comment: Please edit your question, adding example code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Additionally, please edit your question to explain how you are building your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It would help if you would show the code in which you are trying to import a class;, the class to be imported including its containing package; and the complete pathname(s) starting with the root of all classes involved.

Answer (score -2):

To import the java package into a class, we need to use the java import keyword which is used to access the package and its classes into the java program. Use import to access built-in and user-defined packages into your java source file to refer to a class in another package by directly using its name.

Comment: i tried to do this, i have two packages, shui and exercises, and two classes, utility in shui package and product in exercises package, i tried to import utility in product with this code "import shui.utility;", but it says "the import shui.utility cannot be resolved"

Comment: and bruh u really copied and pasted the import definition from google? tf?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).